# Will adding a default value to an existing column or renaming a column lock Postgres tables?

Tags: postgresql

I need to perform two migrations on a 2 million row Postgres table and need to ensure there will be minimal downtime each time they are run i.e. less than 5s.

The migrations are:

1) Add a default value of 0 and change to non null from null to an **existing** bigint column

2) Rename a column

Note: I've found lots of posts stating adding a new column with a default value to a big table will cause locking but not about adding a default to an existing column.

Will these lock the table up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) describes in meticulous detail which variant of `ALTER TABLE` will take which lock.

`SET DEFAULT`, `SET NOT NULL` and `RENAME COLUMN` all take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock.

That is inconvenient, but usually only bad if the `ALTER TABLE` statement takes a long time. Both `SET DEFAULT` and `RENAME COLUMN` are fast, but `SET NOT NULL` will have to scan the table to determine if the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks  Laurenz for providing info on both adding defaults and renaming columns and documentation links. This has helped me move forwards.

Answer (score 6):

As we know that the default values only apply to subsequent INSERT commands; they do not cause rows already in the table to change. This implies that there will be no lock on the table on setting default value to the existing column

Refer the **SET/DROP DEFAULT** section of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

You can also refer [this](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/safe-operations-for-high-volume-postgresql/) article to know the safe operations for high volume PostgreSql.

Comment: Thanks Lakhan for your reply and for your useful links.

Comment: Well, there *will* be a lock on the table, but only a short one. Still, if there is a lot of activity on the table, the `ALTER TABLE` will have to queue behind concurrent lock requests and will block all statements that come after it until it has got its lock and completed. If you have only short transactions, that shouldn't be a big problem, but with long transactions it is.